# MySQL syntax error (INSERT)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I need help with a simple MySQL insert query. I have the following code:

```
INSERT INTO reads (location, meter, value) VALUES ('$_GET[location]', '$meter', '$value')
```

Which, after PHP, translates into:

```
INSERT INTO reads (`location`, `meter`, `value`) VALUES ('1234','1111','2505')
```

This query returns the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'reads (`location`, `meter`, `value`) VALUES
>   ('1234','1111','2505')' at line 1

I have gone over my syntax many times and just cant figure out what is wrong with my query. Can anyone spot it?

Comment: reads is the word it does not like. See the list of not allowed words: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

you might circumvent it by using `reads` so it uses the table name as a label instead

Comment: If the values are stored as integers, then you don't need the single quotes around the values in your INSERT statement.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh That still returns the same error

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Thanks for the great answer. That was the solution. If you want to post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Too short answers are demoted to comment again. Thanks anyhow  :)